# segmentation fault(core dumped) in C dealing with getchar

Tags: c++, c, segmentation-fault

I try to read a formula full of `-,(,),|,&,>,=` characters. I want to skip the blanks and end-of-line characters and put the others in an array to use them efficiently.

The code is:

```
int main()

{
    char *array;
    int i=0,j;
    char c=getchar();
    array=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
    while (c != EOF)
    {
      if( islower(c) || (c!=' ' && c!='\n'))
      {
        array[i]=c;
        i++;
        array=(char*)realloc(array,sizeof(char)*(i+1));
      }
   }
}
```

My input is:

```
    -(-(a&k) > ( -((a|-k)
          |c   ))
```

but it gives me `segmentation fault`. What should I do?

Comment: Among other problems, `getchar()` returns an `int` result, which should be stored in an `int`, not in a `char`. This lets you distinguish the value `EOF` from any valid character value.

Comment: You need to check for whether `realloc` succeeds or not. And decide whether you are using C or C++.

Comment: See http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: I am beginner at implementing in C and also writing a problem in this site. So I am sorry for the bad implementation, tag problems and question-writing problems. Thank you for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are managing memory yourself and that you are never changing the value of `c` which, if it's originally different from `EOF`, will cause an infinite loop. Use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string):

```
int main() {
    std::string array;
    char c = getchar();
    while (c != EOF) {
        if(islower(c) || (c!=' ' && c!='\n'))
            array.push_back(c);
        c = getchar();
    }
}
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/53e53816fb0cde78)

Not only this is easier to read and to write, but it is also much more efficient than keep reallocating memory at every loop.

Comment: @MattMcNabb, The `int` gets implicitly converted to `char`. I don't see the problem, care to explain?

Comment: `getchar()` returns an int. It can return every possible `unsigned char` value , in addition to `EOF`. Therefore if you try to store the result in a `char` then `EOF` will either overlap with a valid character, or never match any char. Also, `islower` expects value in the range `0...UCHAR_MAX-1` (although some implementations of it can handle negative values as an extension).

Answer (score 0):

for C

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(){
    char *array;
    int ch, i=0, capacity = 16;
    array = malloc(capacity);
    while(EOF!=(ch = getchar())){//It is necessary to receive an int return value is in order to properly compare EOF.
        if(!isspace(ch)){//islower not necessary when OR(||) condition
            array[i++]=ch;
            if(i==capacity)//Efficiency is not good of character by character
                array = realloc(array, capacity += 16);
        }
    }
    array[i] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", array);
    free(array);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should also check the return value of realloc and malloc. But it is unlikely to have caused the segment fault for the number of characters in this input. I suspect the direct cause and is that the loop does not terminate.